# Startup script run as a specific user Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, startup

So I have a user, userA on Ubuntu.  When the machine starts I want to add a script to /etc/rc0.d called startService

From inside of this script it will start several services using three scripts

```
startServiceA.sh
startServiceB.sh
startServiceC.sh
```

I'd like those three scripts to be started from userA, not root.  How would I achieve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running a script as a specific user, not about programming. It appears to be better suited for [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands like: su, sudo, runuser

Be sure to check the man pages.

This site might be able to help you also
http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands inside your startup script with:

```
sudo -u <username> ....
```

Note: you will need to to preface every command in the file that you want to run as another user. I'd recommend making a variable at the top of your script like so:

```
SUDO="sudo -u <username>"
```

Then just do: `$SUDO <command>`